# ClassNotFoundException but library present

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My Java service running in Google App Engine in the standard environment  is giving me a ClassNotFoundException although I can see through the Stackdriver debug screen that the library was deployed.  The service runs fine locally and the other libraries are being picked up ok.  In fact, other classes in the library are being read okay.  The class in question has java 6 bytecode so it should be readable by google's JDK.  Any ideas of what would cause this or what I should look at?  Thanks

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Comment: what is the name of the class? it is your own library?

Comment: Not using eclipse.  Class is CSSLexer from the jstyleparser-1.20 library, written by someone else. Thx for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the 3rd-party library was using a restricted class in the standard environment (the "sandbox").  White-list of classes is here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/jrewhitelist

Didn't see the error message in the logs (maybe it was buried somewhere), but found it in the AppeEngine dashboard page.